# BroadcastReceiver active all the time

Tags: android

I have a app that has call blocking feature in it and that work is done by class BroadcastReceiver. When I install this app, the call is blocked always no matter what. How to get rid of this? I want this app to be active only when App is up and running . If I stop the service the App should not block the call. Thank you any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you the developer, or a user? If the latter, then you need to bring it up to the programmer of the app. If the former, then simply don't respond to the received broadcast when the app is not "active".